# IntelliJ 14 Linux, not recognizing environment variables

Tags: bash, intellij-idea, environment-variables, linux-mint, intellij-14

I have recently installed intellij on linux and I need an encryption key to connect to a database which is set in my ~/.bashrc and in troubleshooting I have also set it in my ~/.bash_profile.  I have even tried placing it in my /etc/environment file

basically it looks like this in bash profile and bashrc (obviously not actually foo but for the example)

```
export ENCRYPTION_KEY=foo
```

and when i run the echo command

```
echo $ENCRYPTION_KEY
```

it prints foo so i feel like i have set that up properly.

but when I try to run my app it tells me that it cannot resolve ENCRYPTION_KEY

as is true with any other environment variables I have tried to set.

Any thoughts?

IntelliJ 14.2, Linux Mint 17.2

Comment: You have to say what "when I try to run my app" means. How is your "app" related to bash? You're setting env vars for bash, and bash only (basically).

Comment: @4ae1e1 Environment variables are not just for `bash`. The `export` command tells `bash` to add the variable to the environment it creates for *any* child process.

Comment: @chepner That's what I'm asking when I say "how is your 'app' related to bash". I'm saying the "app" is probably not launched from bash.

Comment: You can't set env vars in bash and expect them to show up system-wide. Bash is no init.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I placed it in bashrc because it had worked for me previously on an older version of mint.  But as my question states I tried placing it in several places, maybe it would be more clear if my question stated "where to put environment variables in linux" clearly I don't understand something I thought I did and I'm trying to learn.  Your response is not helpful without offering a solution.

Comment: Please don't be ridiculous. I pointed out the problem in my opening sentence: you have to say what "when I try to run my app" means. The problem is how you launch the app. If it's a child process of bash then it should work. Otherwise it shouldn't, simple as that. Without that info, how can I offer a solution?

Comment: @4ae1e1 my apologies, I do appreciate your help maybe I misread the tone of your comment.  There were two apps I experienced this issue with one using the tomcat run configuration of IntelliJ and the second using a spring boot run configuration.

Comment: I don't know tomcat or spring boot so I'll leave this to someone else, but this info should definitely be part of the question (and a critical part for that matter). I was trying to help by asking for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

So honestly I'm not sure what resolved it, but the only thing I did was xrdp into my machine to check something.  And now when I tried it today, it works... This is after I restarted the machine, restarted IntelliJ multiple times, tried running the source command for bashrc and bash profile.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Intellij 
1. Open run/debug configurations.
2. See Environment variables 
3. Add key and value pairs for config.